# How do you use 'flow' from Lodash/FP to pass 'this' along

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, lodash

I'm trying to understand how to use Lodash's 'flow', in particular I'd like to understand how to use the fact that it passes the original caller's 'this' along to each function in the chain.  I came across this post -- [What does the lodash flow function do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510145/what-does-the-lodash-flow-function-do) -- and in the 2nd answer it addresses this ("All the applied functions will use the this argument of the caller in case that is desired") but I don't really understand what that means.  I tried to work up a short code sample on my own, but it doesn't work, probably because I'm missing the point of the exercise.  Any pointers much appreciated.

```
const fp = require('lodash/fp')


const a = x => {
    console.log(`in a this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
    return x * 2
}


const b = x => {
    console.log(`in b this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
    return x / 3
}
const c = x => {
    console.log(`in c this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
    return x + 5
}

const obj1 = {
    a,
    title: "hi there, the title"
}

const all = fp.pipe([obj1.a, b, c])

console.log(all(10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `_.bind()` the `this` of the function created by pipe/flow to an object. When invoked all functions in the pipe will be called with the bound `this` value:

```js
const { pipe, bind } = _

function a(x) {
  console.log(`in a this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
  return x * 2
}


function b(x) {
  console.log(`in b this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
  return x / 3
}

function c(x) {
  console.log(`in c this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
  return x + 5
}

const obj1 = {
  title: "hi there, the title"
}

const all = bind(pipe([a, b, c]), obj1)

console.log(all(10))
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Old answer: You'll need to manually bind the functions to `obj1`. To do so, you can't use array functions, because they'll automatically use the `this` of context they were define in.

```js
const { pipe, bind } = _

function a(x) {
  console.log(`in a this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
  return x * 2
}


function b(x) {
  console.log(`in b this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
  return x / 3
}

function c(x) {
  console.log(`in c this is ${JSON.stringify(this)}`)
  return x + 5
}

const obj1 = {
  title: "hi there, the title"
}

const all = pipe([a, b, c].map(fn => bind(fn, obj1)))

console.log(all(10))
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: but doesn't mapping everything to bind it to `obj1` sort of obviate that feature of `pipe`?  That is, is it not `pipe` itself that's supposed to be passing `this` along to each subsequent function?  Here we're binding all the functions anyway, so their `this` will always be `obj1`.  I had thought that the nice feature of `pipe` might be to allow some flexibility in some manner....

Comment: It took me some time to understand the esoteric sentence in the description, but it seems you can bind the function created by the pipe. See updated answer.