# Apply same arguments to Lodash flow callbacks

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, lodash

The Lodash `flow()` function works, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53510145/376483), by giving it a bunch of functions in an array. The result of the previous function will be applied to the next one.

And this is exactly what is problematic for my use case, as it throws away any arguments provided. I need to pass them on to the next function in line, instead of just the return value <sup>*)</sup>.

*<sup>*)</sup> Yes, the return value should get returned modified and be passed on the next function*

*Using `flow()` is just what I came up with. Any other solution achieving the goal is ok as  well.*

---

What it **does**:

```js
_.flow( [ firstFn, secondFn ] )
( first, second, third ) => firstFn( first, second, third ) => return first * first
( first ) => secondFn( first )
```

What it **should do**:

```js
_.flow( [ firstFn, secondFn ] )
( first, second, third ) => firstFn( first, second, third ) => return first * first
( first, second, third ) => secondFn( resultFromFirstFn, second, third )
```

---

Here's some code to demo it:

```js
const checkLog = ( val, attr, group ) => {
  console.log( val, attr, group )
  return val
}

// This basically is "easy to use"-API and what will be mostly used.
const Callbacks = {
    demo: [ _.trim, _.toLower, checkLog ],
}

// _.cond() is just a switch
// [ <condition-to-exec-cb>, <cb-if-cond-true> ] 
const cond = _.cond( _.map( 
  [
    [ _.stubTrue, Callbacks.demo ],
  ],
  // Monkey patching _.flow() to each array of cond/cb above
  cb => _.set( cb, '1', _.flow( _.last( cb ) ) ) 
) )

const res = _.map( {
  " city": " Sample City",
  "street": "Sample Street",
}, cond )

console.log( res )
```

*Note: In case you wonder about why I write it like this: There's a single line comment that points to which part will get altered and extended *a lot* in the future and this must, due to the target group working there, be simple. So it's just an array of stacked callbacks.*

Comment: Just to check if I understood this, you want to do something like `pipe = _.flow( takes2Params, takes3Params)` and call that like `pipe("param1", "param2", "param3")` then expect the second call to be `takes3Params(resultFromTakes2Params, "param2", "param3)`. Is this correct?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes! I edited the question to (hopefully) clarify it.

Comment: @VLAZ What I tried and couldn't get to work, was applying `_.partial()` to the array of callbacks with placeholders `_`.

Comment: OK thank you. Unfortunately, I don't think that's very easy to do using `flow()`. It's supposed to work with unary functions (aside from optionally the first one). You can probably do some gymnastics by trying to carry parameters as tuples but I think it's going to be awkward and annoying. I guess `partial()` is the best you can really go for but a more general solution might be an algebraic structure like a functor that carries all arguments through the entire chain.

Comment: @VLAZ Using `flow()` is not a must. I am completely open to any other solution.

Comment: OK, I'm trying to find something that might help. I'll try to post an answer soon.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `_.flow()` is that it expects everything after the first argument to be a unary function so it can pass the result through all of them. This presents a challenge when you want to apply the same set of arguments to all function and only alter the first one. There are a few ways you could go about this.

## Using Lodash

You could leverage [`_.partialRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partialRight) to do a partial allocation of every function. `partialRight` will apply arguments from right to left depending on how many arguments the function takes.

```js
const fn = (a, b, c, d) => console.log(a, b, c, d);

// behaves similar to (a, b) => console.log(a, b, "yak", "zebra")
const newFn = _.partialRight(fn, "yak", "zebra");

newFn("alpaca", "beaver");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

However you can still pass arguments left to right and this would push the partially applied arguments to right:

```js
const fn = (a, b, c, d) => console.log(a, b, c, d);

// behaves similar to (a, b) => console.log(a, b, "yak", "zebra")
const newFn = _.partialRight(fn, "yak", "zebra");

newFn("alpaca", "beaver", "cat");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Assuming all of the function will have *at most* take `n` amount of arguments we can:

1. Get an array of `n` arguments to be applied to all functions.
2. Get all functions.
3. Do `partialRight` on all functions using all but the first argument. Since we've applied `n-1` arguments to each, now all of them can be called as if they are unary.
4. Use `flow` on the new functions from step **3.**
5. Start the chain using the first argument.

This will then call all functions such that the *first argument* is the *last result* and the second and onwards arguments would be based on the initial ones thus always the same for all functions

```js
function nAryFlow(argsArray, ...fns) { //1. and 2. - get arguments and functions
  const start = argsArray[0];
  const rest = argsArray.slice(1);

  const convertedFns = fns.map(f => _.partialRight(f, ...rest)) //3. Turn all functions into unary ones
  return _.flow( //4. `flow` through the functions
    ...convertedFns
  )(start); //5. use the initial fist argument to kick things off
}

const fn1 = (who1, who2, who3) =>    `${who1}, ${who2}, and ${who3} are best friends.`;
const fn2 = (friends, who2, who3) => `${friends} Especially ${who2} and ${who3}.`;
const fn3 = (story, who2) =>         `${story} They all met at a party thrown by ${who2}`;

const args = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"];

const result = nAryFlow(args, fn1, fn2, fn3);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

## Without using Lodash

All of the above can very easily be done without Lodash. Instead, we can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to go through all of the functions and apply the arguments. This time, we're directly applying them instead of pre-processing the functions but the overall operation and effect is the same:

1. The first function takes all the arguments.
2. Any further function takes the result of the last function and the second argument onwards from the start:

```js
function nAryFlow(argsArray, ...fns) {
  const start = argsArray[0];
  const rest = argsArray.slice(1);
  
  return fns.reduce((last, f) => f(last, ...rest), start);
}

const fn1 = (who1, who2, who3) =>    `${who1}, ${who2}, and ${who3} are best friends.`;
const fn2 = (friends, who2, who3) => `${friends} Especially ${who2} and ${who3}.`;
const fn3 = (story, who2) =>         `${story} They all met at a party thrown by ${who2}`;

const args = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"];

const result = nAryFlow(args, fn1, fn2, fn3);

console.log(result)
```

### Variation using more higher order functions

Just as a variation, this could be split up into multiple higher order functions which might produce a nicer syntax for some situations `nAryFlow(f1, f2, f3, fN)(arg1, arg2, arg3, argN)`:

```js
function nAryFlow(...fns) {
  return function (...args) {
    const start = args[0];
    const rest = args.slice(1);

    return fns.reduce((last, f) => f(last, ...rest), start);
  }
}
const fn1 = (who1, who2, who3) =>    `${who1}, ${who2}, and ${who3} are best friends.`;
const fn2 = (friends, who2, who3) => `${friends} Especially ${who2} and ${who3}.`;
const fn3 = (story, who2) =>         `${story} They all met at a party thrown by ${who2}`;

const chain = nAryFlow(fn1, fn2, fn3);

const result1 = chain("Alice", "Bob", "Carol");
const result2 = chain("Rachel Green", "Monica Geller", "Chandler Bing");

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

## Using a Functor

For a slightly different take here, you can use an algebraic structure called [Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_(functional_programming)) to ease the syntax. The essential thing about functors is that they have a `.map()` method that accepts a function. If you're reminded of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) then you're not wrong.

The basic idea is that the functor holds a value and allows it to be modified with functions via `.map()`. It can then dictate how the function is applied to its value. The result of `.map` is always the same type of functor as what was already mapped, so you can always continue mapping and be sure that the application would be the same every time. With arrays you always get a new array of the same length with every member transformed. Other functors can apply the function given to `.map()` different to what an array does but it would always be consistent.

So, background done, here is how this functor can look like:

```js
class NAryFlow {
  constructor(argsArray) {
    this.value = argsArray[0];
    this.rest = argsArray.slice(1);
  }
  
  static of(argsArray) {
    return new NAryFlow(argsArray);
  }

  map(fn) {
    return NAryFlow.of(
      [ fn(this.value, ...this.rest), ...this.rest ]
    );
  }
}

const fn1 = (who1, who2, who3) =>    `${who1}, ${who2}, and ${who3} are best friends.`;
const fn2 = (friends, who2, who3) => `${friends} Especially ${who2} and ${who3}.`;
const fn3 = (story, who2) =>         `${story} They all met at a party thrown by ${who2}`;

const result = NAryFlow.of(["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"])
  .map(fn1)
  .map(fn2)
  .map(fn3)
  .value;

console.log(result)
```

A similar idea as the two others above - we take the arguments, and apply them all to each function we give to `.map()`. Every next time we call `.map()` the first argument would be the last result.

And here is a slight variation using [ES6 getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). I think it has a slightly better syntax but wanted to keep the previous implementation simpler.

```js
class NAryFlow {
  constructor(argsArray) {
    this.args = argsArray;
  }
  
  static of(argsArray) {
    return new NAryFlow(argsArray);
  }

  map(fn) {
    return NAryFlow.of(
      [ fn(...this.args), ...this.rest ]
    );
  }
  
  get value() {
    return this.args[0];
  }
  
  get rest() {
    return this.args.slice(1);
  }
}

const fn1 = (who1, who2, who3) =>    `${who1}, ${who2}, and ${who3} are best friends.`;
const fn2 = (friends, who2, who3) => `${friends} Especially ${who2} and ${who3}.`;
const fn3 = (story, who2) =>         `${story} They all met at a party thrown by ${who2}`;

const result = NAryFlow.of(["Alice", "Bob", "Carol"])
  .map(fn1)
  .map(fn2)
  .map(fn3)
  .value;

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`flow` doesn't throw any arguments, it's just how javascript functions work, they don't respect the a particular signature, you can call a function that only takes 1 parameter with 100 parameters and that won't throw an error.

Also `flow` is defined such that it passes the initial parameters all to the first function regardless of whether it's going to use them all or not.

You can create your own `flow` function(since it is a [simple one](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/flow.js)) that only passes the exact amount of parameters a function needs and keep the rest for the rest of functions. To know how many parameters a function takes, you can [check its `length` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4138012/9867451) like so:

```
function flow(funcs) {
  const length = funcs.length;
  for(let func of funcs) {
    if (typeof func !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('Expected a function');
    }
  }

  return function(...args) {
    let result = args[0];
    for(let func of funcs) {
      result = func.apply(this, args.slice(0, func.length));  // call this function with only as many args as it needs
      args = [result, ...args.slice(func.length)];            // args becomes the result + the rest of args after the previous call
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

**Note:** This won't work if one of the functions uses the rest parameters, in that case `length` will return `0`. You can't know how many parameters that functions takes. If you wan to call that function with all the available parameters, then just change the `for` loop above to:

```
for(let func of funcs) {
  result = func.apply(this, args.slice(0, func.length || +Infinity));  // if 'func.length' is 0, '+Infinity' is used instead which will use all the available args
  args = [result, ...args.slice(func.length || +Infinity)];            // same goes here, '.slice(+Infinity)' will result in an empty array. 'result' will always be present which is the expected behavior
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function flow(funcs) {
  const length = funcs.length;
  for(let func of funcs) {
    if (typeof func !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('Expected a function');
    }
  }

  return function(...args) {
    let result = args[0];
    for(let func of funcs) {
      result = func.apply(this, args.slice(0, func.length));  // call this function with only as many args as it needs
      args = [result, ...args.slice(func.length)];            // args becomes the result + the rest of args after the previous call
    }
    return result;
  }
}


function square(n) {
  return n * n;
}

function add(a, b, c) {
  return a + b + c;
}

console.log(flow([square, add])(2, 3, 4));
```